# Parse/Get HTML title element from a PHP file for an Ajax  call

Tags: php, html, ajax, parsing

I am trying to get the title element's content that is contained in a echo statement of a PHP file.

I am using a PHP file for a website that when accessed by a Ajax call it returns only part of the page, but when accessed directly it returns the entire page.

That much is working fine. But I would like to change the title of the page when it is accessed via the Ajax call, the innerHTML of the title tag  is what I'm trying to get.

```
if (empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
echo '
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <head>
        <title>Products at Avrent</title>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/htmlcharset=utf-8"   />
```

With a HTML file this code works.

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['url']))  {
    $url = $_GET['url'];
    $html = file_get_html($url);
    /* get page's title */
    preg_match("/<title>(.+)<\/title>/siU", $html, $matches);
    $title = $matches[1];
    echo $title;
}
?>
```

But it returns gibberish when I try using it with a PHP file.

Can someone help me find a PHP script that will work on a PHP file?

Comment: You should try to use some different solution for partial rendering since what you're doing right now is ridiculous

Comment: You really ought to parse HTML with something such as DOMDocument.  Regex really isn't the right tool for the job.

Comment: @Fenec Suppose you give me at least hint of a different solution. I would be happy to use a different solution, although the one I'm using works fine.

Comment: @GordonM I am using simple_html_dom.php to parse HTML but it didn't seem to work for elements within the Head section. Besides my immediate problem is parsing PHP and simple_html_dom.php doesn't work at all on PHP files. But thanks for the feed back.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I've gathered: you have a bunch of HTML pages. You have an index.php script that takes a URL, loads up the HTML from that URL, swaps out the title, then spits the HTML back out?

First of all, why do you have things set up like that? If you insist...

You (at the *very* least) should do this:

**index.php**
Remove the RegEx. You're using an HTML parser; use that!

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['url']))  {
    $url = $_GET['url'];
    $html = file_get_html($url);
    /* get page's title */
    $title = $html->find('title', 0)->innertext;
    echo $title;
}
?>
```

**ajax_page.php**
Set title from variable.

```
if (empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
echo '
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <head>
        <title>' . $page_title . '</title>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/htmlcharset=utf-8"   />
```

Then, from index.php:

```
$page_title = "INSERT THE PAGE TITLE HERE";
require "ajax_page.php";
```

Comment: Thank you primatology for your attempt to help, the code for getting the title on HTML pages returns an error "trying to get property of non Object". But that isn't the problem the code for getting the title from a HTML page that I'm using works fine. I'm trying to do the same thing with the PHP file. I don't want to change the title in the PHP file I want to parse the file and get the title contents.

Comment: Oh my mistake, try now. Added an index (second parameter) to $html->find.